# Export spatial data from Web Map

Tags: leaflet, export, web-mapping, extract

I am trying to get the polygon data from the following leaflet web map http://www.cityfibre.com/rollout/.

I am not really sure what kind of format I should be looking for (geojson, xml, etc..) but I tried the following with no luck.

I go to inspect the element -> network tab -> XHR , I then refresh the page and check the response but can't find anything related.

Any ideas?[image]

Comment: The construction sites are published as a raster tile layer so you can't get vectors from the service. I would suggest to contact the company. Ask about the license of their data by the same.

Comment: Thanks, Is there a way to extract the entire layer as raster?